# For iPad Developers: How to view an image selected from photo library’s popover in a UIImageView, iPad

Tags: ipad, objective-c

I am working on an application for iPad, it is working fine until i reached this point:

The app shows the popover for the photo library, but when I choose the photo, the popover doesn't hide, and I also want it to view the selected image in a UIImageView, however i do not know how.

I am sure there is something wrong in the didFinishpickingMediaWithInfo function. here is the function's code:

```
 -(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishpickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    //bgImage is a UIImageView
bgImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

// Dismiss UIImagePickerController and release it [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
[picker.view removeFromSuperview]; 
[picker release];
}
```

My first question is: What am I supposed to add to this function for viewing the selected photo in the UIImageView? (When I click on the photo from the photo library in the simulator, neither the photo library hide nor the image is viewed in the specified UIImageView)

2- I have read that I should've used UIImage instead of UIImageView.. Is this true? If yes, what about the interface builder? There is nothing called UIImage?

Comment: Agreed, definitely a Stack Overflow question. iOS development questions are answered there all the time.

Comment: I don't see why this community isn't about Apple's Development Software to be used on Apple's Hardware...

Answer (score 1):

To close the image picker, use:

```
[[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

What you get from

```
bgImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
```

is not an UIImageView, it's a UIImage. To get it displayed, you need to have a UIImageView in your UI somewhere, and set the view's image with what you just got from the picker:

```
imageView.image = bgImage
```

Hope this helps